# Is background-position-x (background-position-y) a standard W3C CSS property?

Tags: css, background-position

I'm worried about `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`. Gecko (Firefox) and Presto (Opera) don't support them, but Webkit (Chrome, Safari) does...

Does anyone know (with official references) if this is (or will be) included in the standard?

Comment: Not found in the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

Comment: @Joseph I did and didn't find things from W3C. But it was the same for <canvas> a while ago... And now it is in standards I guess (I didn't verify)

Comment: Firefox is the only major browser that does not support this.
Go to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=550426 and vote.

Comment: You can [vote on this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=550426) to try and convince the Firefox developers to include it in Gecko

Comment: These properties are non-standard. Also note that Webkit (Safari, Chrome) implements them but they return different values than the standard background-position if the user zoomed the page. While background-position remains consistent when zooming, background-position-[xy] adjusts to the zoomed currently rendered coordinates. Tested on Chromium 34.0.1847.116

Comment: Please consider the new answer with April 2014 update from W3C. These properties ARE now part of the standard.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`background-position-x` and `background-position-y` are now part of the [level 4 of Backgrounds and Borders standard](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Apr/0188.html).

> RESOLVED: background-position-x/-y, background-repeat-x/-y
>           approved for level 4 of backgrounds and borders.

Comment: Browser support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-position), however: Firefox doesn't support it at all :(

Answer (score 129):

[Splitting `background-position` into `-x` and `-y` was proposed for CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/9) but it got rejected as the working group “considered the use case too weak to introduce new properties for.” Additionally, there seemed to be [some ambiguity concerns](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Aug/0419.html) with [multiple background images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) and [CSSOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/), the API behind CSS. I’m not sure how WebKit and Trident did implement them and how they addressed these concerns.

The [CSS WG blob has just reported](http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/03/10/resolutions-26/) yesterday that there will be “no change to `background-position` or `transform-origin` syntaxes.” [The reason is probably due to not getting any further delays.](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0898.html)

Maybe it will get added to CSS 4. There is a [current thread on the www-style@w3.org mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Feb/0618.html) that you might find interesting.

---

**Update**    So apparently these properties have been approved for CSS 4 (see [[CSSWG] Minutes Telecon 2014-04-16](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Apr/0188.html)):

> RESOLVED: `background-position-x`/`-y`, `background-repeat-x`/`-y` approved for level 4 of backgrounds and borders.

Comment: OK, with all your links, I'm now sure that it won't be standard for a long time! Thanks!

Comment: Good answer, not the one I wanted to hear though.  :/  Upvoted.

Comment: It seems that only Firefox doesn't support it, since Opera uses Blink rendering engine http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y. Maybe it could be great that w3c standardizes what browsers have already implemented :/

Comment: Please consider the new answer with April 2014 update from W3C. These properties ARE now part of the standard.

Comment: what about the real support for this?

Comment: @egid So true! In fact I got here researching options to make my sprite handling code simpler!

Answer (score 1):

I guess in some sense you've already answered your own question.
No, both background-position-x and background-position-y are nonstandard.

Comment: Browser support (as history and Internet Explorer shows) doesn't have necessarily have anything to do with the standards

Comment: that's exactly why I'm added 'in some sense' ) nevertheless, those properties are non-standard. Though quite useful )

Comment: Well I would have needed it, but as they won't be included in any standard for a long time, I prefer to have a longer CSS that works in every browser, that a shorter CSS that is buggy for FF, Op.