# How-to set background-position-x?

Tags: css, opera

How Do i set background-position-x on Opera?

```
div#logocontainer{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image: url(../img/WatermarkMP.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I have the following CSS rule, it will display correctly on Chrome and Safari, desktop and mobile versions. But it will not work on Opera, that does not seem to support the    background-position-x: 50%; background-position-y: 50%; rules. Do I have to script this so that it's compatible with Opera? How do I work around this to support opera also?

It also does not seem to round jQuery Mobile corners...

Comment: Does it work on Firefox?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to set `background-position: 50% 50%`. Those `-x` and `-y` properties are only supported in Internet Explorer and Webkit browsers.

Comment: Why is that? To my knowledge, most other compound properties of that sort can be split up into their components across all systems (such as `margin` consisting of `margin-left`, `margin-right`, `margin-top`, and `margin-bottom`).

Comment: Thanks! So the correct way is to use background-position only? Or do other browsers need the -x -y ?

Comment: background-position: 50% 50%; works on every browser, forget about -x -y as duri said, they are not widely supported

Comment: @JAB Unfortunately, they have never been in any spec. See http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Tracker/issues/9

Comment: Ah, I see. And according to that document there aren't enough situations where that behavior would be useful.

Comment: @JAB, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property

Comment: @Kirby Well what do you know, `-x` and `-y` now are part of the standard.