# Is it possible to change only the Y value of background position in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change only Y value of background position in CSS?

`background-position-y` is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only by reading (with JS) the current value of `background-position` (using a computed style method if it isn't set inline), parsing it to read the X value and then setting it again using the X value you just retrieved.

There is no way to say "Take the background position X value from the cascade and the Y value from this" in CSS.

Comment: @Chev — There is no way to say "Take the background position X value from the cascade and the Y value from this" in CSS. (I'll add that to the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
background-position-y: 10px;
```

Worked fine for me

Answer (score 1):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-position-x) and [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property), `background-position-y` is now standard and supported in all browsers except older versions of Firefox.

> background-position-x/-y, background-repeat-x/-y approved for level 4 of backgrounds and borders.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. While `background-position` allows only one value to be set, this would define x only and make y center. Everything else, like background-position-y is non-standard and therefore only supported in some browsers.

Comment: That is incorrect. Background-position accepts up to two white-space separated values, be in descriptive coordinates, eg `top center`, relative units, eg `50% 25%` or absolute units, eg `50px 200px`.

Comment: @Terry sorry if I wrote it not clear enough but I didn't say `background-position` allows only 1 value alone but that it ALLOWS to use 1 value only. But as I said this wouldn't solve the original question.

Answer (score 0):

`background-position-y: xpx` should work.

Can you show the code see we can see why it might not be working?

Comment: @Lex — The question explicitly excludes `background-position-y` (presumably because it is non-standard and doesn't have sufficient browser support for the project requirements).

Answer (score -1):

use `background-position:0px ypx;`

Comment: That would change the x value too - you are setting it to 0px;

Comment: but 0px is default value and AFAIK he is not using js