# jQuery UI Touch-Punch plugin is not working

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I have a code working perfectly on a desktop device:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" />
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="my/tools/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" />
<div id="time_roll">&nbsp;</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#time_roll').on('mousedown', function(e){
  x = e['clientX'];
  bgx = parseInt($('#time_roll').css('background-position-x'));
  $(window).on('mousemove', function(e){
    newx = e['clientX'];
    pos = bgx+newx-x;
    if (pos>0)       pos = 0;
    if (pos<-(24*60-1)) pos = -(24*60-1);
    $('#time_roll').css('background-position-x',pos);
    pos = -pos;
    h = parseInt(pos/60);
    m = pos%60;
    if (m.length<2) m = '0'+m;
    $('#time').val(h+':'+m);
  });
})
```

Short remark: my drag'n'drop working only in x-axis.

Unfortunately, DnD is not working on any mobile :(

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you say "is not working" can you be more specific? What device(s) have you tested it on and are there any error messages? If you're on an iOS device, try enabling the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a problem with trying to manipulate the `background-position-x` property. It is not a standard property and isn't supported by some browsers (e.g. Firefox). You should instead parse `background-position` for x and y values, and manipulate those.

See [Is background-position-x (background-position-y) a standard W3C CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property)