# CSS - Background position not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, background, background-position

I have this site here: http://seasonsrestaurant.ca/

and In Firefox my social media icons are all the twitter icon. This is my CSS. How come background position is not working?

```css
ul.social-media li.twitter{
    background-image:url(http://www.seasonsrestaurant.ca/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:0px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}

ul.social-media li.instagram{
    background-image:url(http://www.seasonsrestaurant.ca/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:-26px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}

ul.social-media li.facebook{
    background-image:url(http://www.seasonsrestaurant.ca/images/social.png);
    background-position-x:-52px;
    width:25px;
    height:26px;
}
```

Comment: What is the effect you want to achieve? That might be a more productive question.

Comment: @Alfie The OP has all the social media icons in one image file, regularly spaced like a sprite.  To view the icon of choice, simply shift the image by grid with (26px in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a non-standard CSS property that works in Chrome but not Firefox.

See: [Is background-position-x (background-position-y) a standard W3C CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property)

However, standard background properties will take care of the issue.