# problems with animated background-position-x on different browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I've made a simple menu, every item is 300x100 pixels. There's an image in background positioned -150 pixels, when you mouseover an item it changes to 0 (so entire item has background). It works fine on Chrome, the background goes halfway on mouseover on IE, and the background is constantly positioned 0 on FF. How can I fix it? 
S

HTML:

```
<ul class="wrapper">
    <li id="webd"       class="box"><span class="title">web design</span></li>
    <li id="model"      class="box"><span class="title">3D modeling</span></li>
    <li id="digidraw"   class="box"><span class="title">digital drawing</span></li>
    <li id="other"      class="box"><span class="title">other</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS sample:

```
.box {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color:black;
    z-index: 15;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    font-family: 'web_serveroffregular';
    color:white;
    font-size:x-large;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    background-position-x:-150px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:right;
}

#webd {
    background-image:url(images/webd.png);
}

#webd:hover {
    background-position-x:0px;
}
```

You can view the entire website at http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/ and the CSS at       http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/style.css and http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/galeria.css
if you want.

@edit

changed:

```
background-position-x:-150px;
```

to:

```
background-position: -150px 0px;
```

This works fine on FireFox, but still goes only halfway on IE, `background:fixed` and `backgroud-position:fixed` ruins it for every browser.

Comment: screenshots (first item is mouseover):           
Chrome http://i.imgur.com/LKH9aoeh.png    
Firefox http://i.imgur.com/5cM9qpB.png    
IE      http://i.imgur.com/FWxJ2rQh.png

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not valid CSS. Aren't you forgetting your `{}`s?

Comment: I haven't  forgot, but somehow SO doesn't let me put it in the code, dunno why, I only removed it here.

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y check this article and the support table

Answer (score 0):

`background-position-x` is [invalid CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property). Use `background-position: -150px 0px` instead. Also, the `background-attachment` property must be set to "fixed" for this to work in Firefox and Opera ([according to this page at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp))

Comment: (background-attachment: fixed should background:fixed )(background-position-x:0px - should be background-position: 0 0)first 0 for left 2nd 0 for top

Comment: Without background-attachment:fixed works fine on Chrome and FF, but still the same on IE.