# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'backgroundPositionX' in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't figure out why this thing happens.

```
var thumb_width = 240;
var thumb_height = 180;
$('.video-thumbnail').on({
        'mouseenter': function(){
            var i = 0; var j = 0;
            $(this).id = setInterval(function(){
                $(this).animate({
                    'background-position-x': -(j * thumb_width),
                    'background-position-y': -(i * thumb_height)
                });
                i++; j++;
            }, 1000);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Side note: You can use [.mouseenter()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of on.('mouseenter', function() {...

Answer (score 1):

Because `setInterval` runs in `Window` context. In order to fix it you should explicitly provide proper object context. You have couple of options:

Using `$.proxy`:

```
$('.video-thumbnail').on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        var i = 0; var j = 0;
        $(this).id = setInterval($.proxy(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                'background-position-x': -(j * thumb_width),
                'background-position-y': -(i * thumb_height)
            });
            i++; j++;
        }, this), 1000);
    }
});
```

Or using reference to `this`:

```
$('.video-thumbnail').on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        var i = 0; var j = 0, self = this;
        $(this).id = setInterval(function() {
            $(self).animate({
                'background-position-x': -(j * thumb_width),
                'background-position-y': -(i * thumb_height)
            });
            i++; j++;
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: As third option you could use [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: I thought about including this option in the list, but `$.proxy` is iteself `bind` cross-browser implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming a wrong context in the `setInterval`'s callback, as `setInterval` is bound to the global object (`window`).

Also the `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` aren't part of any CSS specification and you cannot set them apart (read more in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property/9653939#9653939)).

Try this:

```
...
var $this = $(this);
$this.id = setInterval(function() {
  var xPos = -(j * thumb_width);
  var yPos = -(i * thumb_height);
  $this.animate('background-position', xPos + 'px ' + yPos + 'px');
  ++i;
  ++j;
}, 1000);
...
```