# Polyfill for CSS `background-position-x/y`? jquery-backgroundfix not working

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, background-position, polyfills

Expanding on [Is background-position-x (background-position-y) a standard W3C CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property) -- is there a polyfill for CSS `background-position-x/y`?

I found https://github.com/liuxuanzy/jquery-backgroundfix but I'm having some trouble making it work:

- Pure JS: http://jsbin.com/ripegiqose/1/edit
- Ruby on Rails (Bower + http://rails-assets.org/): http://runnable.com/VL0J_279Y69u6gxa/rails-jquery-backgroundfix