# How to change comma separated css values with Jquery.css Method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to stack background images using only one div container and making sure their position is related to the screen height.  The issue is I can't seem to alter comma separated CSS values.  Here is how I logically thought it would work.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-position-y', '0, ' + windowHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add px at the end:

```
jQuery("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-position', '0, ' + windowHeight+'px');
```

Comment: Yes, I just had it as a global variable.  That was it I just missed the px at the end thanks!  Now  I just need to figure out the math to get the positioning right. :)

Answer (score 0):

`background-position-y` only takes one value. It should not be comma separated. You may be confused with `background-position` which takes two values, `x` and `y` position.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    $("#home-bg.bg-1").css('background-position-y', windowHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `background-position` and set both values. Don't use `background-position-y`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property) why.

If you still want to use it, then you have to remove `0,`, because `background-position-y` only takes **1** argument and don't forget to add `px` to the value.