# How to change only the y-as on hover?

Tags: html, css

I use a image sprite for each post type. I call a image by using:

The markup that I am using is:

```css
.format {
 height: 60px;
 width: 60px;
 margin: 0 auto;
    float:left;
 background: #d7354a url(http://i.imgur.com/sVTJJMV.png) no-repeat 0 top;

}
span.format:hover { 
  background: #FFF url(http://i.imgur.com/sVTJJMV.png) no-repeat 0 bottom; 
}

.format.image { background-position: 0 0; }
.format.location { background-position: -60px 0; }
.format.text { background-position: -120px 0; }
.format.profile { background-position: -180px 0; }
.format.sound { background-position: -240px 0; }
.format.link { background-position: -300px 0; }
```

```html
<span class="format image"></span>
<span class="format location"></span>
<span class="format text"></span>
```

As you can see it will display three icons. When you hover over one span, the background change to white and the icon to red. The only problem is that `.format:hover` use the same `x-as` as for the `normal` state. I can create for each format type an hover state css, but I was wondering if it is also possible with only one hover, where the x-as will be the one of that format. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to use JS?

Comment: If that is the only way, then I do it with css only and create for each format an hover style...

Comment: If i understood correctly you need background-position to change on hover for each `format` but you want to do it with one `.format:hover` line of css. I don't think you can do it with just css, but i am not sure.

Comment: Yes exactly and ok.. Maybe someone else and otherwise I create simple for each one a hover state..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background` property is a short hand to set a bunch of other properties.
When you use it again in `span.format:hover` you are overriding some of the properties that make it look like you want. Just change the properties you need.

Use this as a rule of thumb: if you are repeating code you are probably doing something wrong.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

```css
.format {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float:left;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/sVTJJMV.png");
  background-color: rgb(215, 53, 74);
}

span.format:hover {
  background-position-y: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
}

.format.image { background-position: 0 0; }
.format.location { background-position: -60px 0; }
.format.text { background-position: -120px 0; }
.format.profile { background-position: -180px 0; }
.format.sound { background-position: -240px 0; }
.format.link { background-position: -300px 0; }
```

```html
<span class="format image"></span>
<span class="format location"></span>
<span class="format text"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you update the `background` property on hover, you will actually have to redeclare all the x- and y- positions for each link element individually. `background` is simply a shorthand property and therefore will not intelligently "merge" with any exisitng `background` property values, but override it.

You can of course use `background-position-y` to override only the y positioning of the element, but [it is not supported in some browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property). It is only [recently (ca. 2014) introduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property) to the W3C specifications. An alternative would be using pseudo-elements, but I consider [the solution posted by @nicooga as the best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34695979/395910).

With regards to the pseudo-element solution, you can do it as follow:

The trick is to double the height of the pseudo-element (using `bottom: -100%`), and then moving the pseudo-element upwards by its own height (using `top: -100%`) on hover. In that case, you will only have to declare your background positions once for all your elements.

```css
.format {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.format::before {
  background: #d7354a url(http://i.imgur.com/sVTJJMV.png) no-repeat 0 top;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
span.format:hover::before {
  background-color: #fff;
  top: -100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.format.image::before {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.format.location::before {
  background-position: -60px 0;
}
.format.text::before {
  background-position: -120px 0;
}
.format.profile::before {
  background-position: -180px 0;
}
.format.sound::before {
  background-position: -240px 0;
}
.format.link::before {
  background-position: -300px 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="format image"></span>
<span class="format location"></span>
<span class="format text"></span>
```